Laravel 11 not able to send simple Email regularly
I have developed a Laravel 11 application that is supposed to send an email upon user registration. The application rarely sends an email except for a few registrations.
Here is my code:
Route file:
Route::get('/program/touching-lives-at-christmas/register', [PublicController::class, 'form_tlc']);

Route::post('/program/touching-lives-at-christmas/register', [PublicController::class, 'register_save_tlc']);

Controller file:
class PublicController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function register_save_tlc(Request $request){
        
        
        $tlc= new Tlc();
        $participant= new Participant();
        $part1=Participant::where('email', $request->email)->get();
        $check=Participant::where('email', $request->email)->count();

        $centerl= Tlc_leader::where('center', $request->center)->get();
        foreach($centerl as $center_loc){
            $data = [
                'title'=> $request->title,
                'name'=> $request->name,
                'package' => $request->tlc_package,
                'center' => $request->center,
                'city' => $request->city,
                'coordinator_name'=> $center_loc->coordinator_name,
                'phone_no'=> $center_loc->phone_no

            ];
        
            
    
            Mail::to($request->email)->send(new Signup($data));

        }

Email template:
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            TKP Registration confirmation
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        
        TLC Registration Confirmation.
         <center><img src="https://forms.tkpmission.org/images/banner.png" style="width: 100%; height: auto" alt=""></center>

Dear {{$data['title']}} {{$data['name']}},

This to acknowledge your registration for TLC 2024.

You have indicated indicate in {{$data['package']}}
(the TLC Package)
in 
      @if($data['package'] !=null || $data['package']!="")
              {{$data['center']}} Center .

      @else
      {{$data['city']}} City .

      @endif

Mailable class
class Signup extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     */

     public $data;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        //
        $this->data= $data;
    }

    /**
     * Get the message envelope.
     */
    public function envelope(): Envelope
    {
        return new Envelope(
            subject: 'Signup'
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the message content definition.
     */
    public function content(): Content
    {
        return new Content(
            view: 'success',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the attachments for the message.
     *
     * @return array<int, \Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Attachment>
     */
    public function attachments(): array
    {
        return [];
    }
}

.env file
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=<email server>
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=<my email>
MAIL_PASSWORD=<password>
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=<my email>
MAIL_FROM_NAME=App

Please, I need help on how to figure this out.

Do you really mean the email is rarely sent, or actually that it's rarely received? There is a big difference between the two. What evidence do you have that it never sends the email? Do you have logs? Errors? Debugging steps you can show us? You've dumped us some code with no evidence, no information, no technical details and just a very vague statement about the final outcome. Provide a [mre] of the issue with clear, specific information and we might be able to help you more. Remember we can't run your code or debug your environment. See also [ask]. You can [edit] your post. Thanks.

Sometimes, SMTP ports like 587 may not work over WiFi due to network restrictions. I’ve encountered this issue before. Try sending the email using mobile data—if it works, contact your internet provider to request that they open the necessary ports, or try using a VPN.

Based on your comment since this is not occurred always, it will be more efficient to identify the issue that may prevent emails from sending. Therefore, you can improve the your code by adding the try-catch as follows. This way you can get more idea on this.
try {
    Mail::to($request->email)->send(new Signup($data));
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Log the exception
}

